# Flickering of 'file' named text

Tags: python, tkinter

https://gemoo.com/tools/upload-video/share/614985887394189312?codeId=v62xQbrjGBBq8&card=614985882998558720&origin=videolinkgenerator

here is the link to the video of the error that i was facing.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.font import Font

class NotepadApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Notepad Clone")
        self.textarea = tk.Text(self.master, wrap="word", undo=True)
        self.textarea.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        self.textarea.bind("<Control-MouseWheel>", self.zoom)
        self.create_menu()
        self.minimized_dims = None  # Store minimized window dimensions

    def create_menu(self):
        menubar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)
        file_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.new_file)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.open_file)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.save_file)
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.master.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

        # Set fixed size for the menu bar to prevent flickering
        self.master.config(menu=menubar, height=1)

    def new_file(self):
        self.textarea.delete(1.0, tk.END)

    def open_file(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*")])
        if file_path:
            try:
                with open(file_path, "r") as file:
                    content = file.read()
                self.textarea.delete(1.0, tk.END)
                self.textarea.insert(1.0, content)
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to open file: {e}")

    def save_file(self):
        content = self.textarea.get(1.0, tk.END)
        file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("Text files", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*")])
        if file_path:
            try:
                with open(file_path, "w") as file:
                    file.write(content)
            except Exception as e:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to save file: {e}")

    def zoom(self, event):
        if self.master.state() == 'iconic':
            return  # If window is minimized, do nothing

        font = Font(font=self.textarea['font'])
        if event.delta > 0:
            # Increase font size
            font.configure(size=max(8, font.actual()['size'] + 2))
        elif event.delta < 0:
            # Decrease font size
            font.configure(size=max(8, font.actual()['size'] - 2))

        # Store current window dimensions
        self.minimized_dims = (self.master.winfo_width(), self.master.winfo_height())
        self.textarea.configure(font=font)
        # Restore window dimensions after changing font size
        if self.minimized_dims:
            self.master.update_idletasks()
            self.master.geometry(f"{self.minimized_dims[0]}x{self.minimized_dims[1]}")

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = NotepadApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

here is the code its fine but during zoom in or out of the text inside the window for some reason idk y but the 'file' written at the menu section is flickering as u can see in the video attacked to the link

Comment: You don't need to create a `Font` object each time zoom is called. Create a font object once, and then just reconfigure the font. The text widget will automatically adapt. The problem might be because you keep calling `configure` on the text widget itself.